# Loop over string returns int32

Tags: loops, go, range

Why does ranging over a string return `int32` value instead of the original character in go unlike other languages?

for example:

```
func main() {

    var s string
    s = "Hello"
    for _, v := range s {
        fmt.Println(v)
    }

}
```

Returns:

```
72
101
108
108
111
```

Should we use conversion like below to get the original character?

```
func main() {

    var s string
    s = "Hello"
    for _, v := range s {
        fmt.Println(string(v))
    }

}
```

Comment: it returns the unicode code https://ascii.cl/, you can do `s[_]` and you'll get the character

Comment: @WilomGfx: It returns Unicode code points. ASCII is a subset.

Comment: You can use `fmt.Printf("%c", v)` or `fmt.Printf("%q", v)`  to print the rune.

Comment: If the language spec says so it is so. There is nothing to know here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)
>
> For statements with range clause
>
> For a string value, the "range" clause iterates over the Unicode code
>   points in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive
>   iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of
>   successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and the second
>   value, of type rune, will be the value of the corresponding code
>   point. If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the
>   second value will be 0xFFFD, the Unicode replacement character, and
>   the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.

---

In Go, a character is a Unicode code point, a Go type `rune` (alias of `int32`). Go `string`s are used to store Unicode code points in UTF-8 encoded form.

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)
>
> Conversions to and from a string type
>
> Converting a signed or unsigned integer value to a string type yields
>   a string containing the UTF-8 representation of the integer. Values
>   outside the range of valid Unicode code points are converted to
>   "\uFFFD".
>
> ```
> string('a')       // "a"
> string(-1)        // "\ufffd" == "\xef\xbf\xbd"
> string(0xf8)      // "\u00f8" == "ø" == "\xc3\xb8"
> type MyString string
> MyString(0x65e5)  // "\u65e5" == "日" == "\xe6\x97\xa5"
> ```

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    helloworld := "Hello, 世界"
    fmt.Println(helloworld)
    for i, r := range helloworld {
        fmt.Println(i, r, string(r))
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/R5sBeGiJzR4

Output:

```
Hello, 世界
0 72 H
1 101 e
2 108 l
3 108 l
4 111 o
5 44 ,
6 32  
7 19990 世
10 30028 界
```

---

References:

[The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

[The Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/)